# HELP here using ajax + jquery nested form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well im new to jquery and ajax and the code below doesnt work after 2nd attemp of submit form... heres the javascript code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
        target:        '#output2',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 

        }; 

        $('#myForm2').submit(function() {



        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
        });

 $('#me').submit(function() {
        $("#div2").load("main.php"); 
        return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    return true; 
    } 
    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {}
```

by the way im using jquery form plugin.....

and for the index.php

```
<form id="me" action="" method="post">
Message: <input type="text" name="mess">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

lastly for the main.php

```
<form id="myForm2" action="index.php" method="post"><div>

                    Name:</td><td><input name="Name" type="text" />

                    <input type="reset"   name="resetButton " value="Reset" />

                    <input type="submit"  name="submitButton" value="Submit1" />



            </div></form>

            <h1>Output Div (#output2):</h1>

            <div id="output2">AJAX response will replace this content.</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: you have to elaborate on "doesn't work"

Comment: when i submit the form in main.php it loads the form of index.php to the division i specified and when i submit again the newly loaded form from index.php ajax does not seem to load it to the desired division but instead redirect to index.php

Answer (score 1):

You downloading your form after page load ( *$("#div2").load("main.php")) and your events are already binded. So when your second form loaded, it's Submit button click event doesn't triger nothing. You have to read about .live() in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Here is my solution (that is just simpl example):

```
$('#myForm2').live("click",function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

Maybe this will work for you.

## UPD

Also you can try this:

1) replace

```
$('#myForm2').live("click",function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});
```

with

```
function MyFormSubmit(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
})
```

2) Add JS code to you myForm2 Submit button `onClick` event

```
    <form id="myForm2" action="index.php" method="post"><div>

                Name:</td><td><input name="Name" type="text" />

                <input type="reset"   name="resetButton " value="Reset" />

                <input type="submit"  name="submitButton" value="Submit1"
                 onClick="javascript:MyFormSubmit(this);return false;"/>



        </div></form>

        <h1>Output Div (#output2):</h1>

        <div id="output2">AJAX response will replace this content.</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: ill try this one.. but it think this does not work on submit button right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove  `action="index.php" method="post"` from your form. Then should it work.

because now it is still making the php post to index.php